# File not found when using variable file names

Tags: makefile, sh

I've just started trying to use static pattern rules and for loops together within makefiles, I'm still relatively new to using makefiles so please forgive me if I've missed something obvious.

In the code below I have tried to use a for loop to create 6 executables, two for each unique file.

Here is the makefile:

```
vpath %.h ../headers/
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -I../headers/
LDFLAGS  :=
SUFFIX   := fileA fileB fileC

memory-%.exe: primary-%.o memory.cpp
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@
timing-%.exe: primary-%.o timing.cpp
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@

all:   for i in $(SUFFIX); \
       do \
       testing-$$i.exe: primary-$$i.o; \
       memory-$$i.exe: primary-$$i.o; \
       done
```

I am met with the error:

```
\bin\sh: 3: memory-fileA.exe:: not found
\bin\sh: 4: timing-fileA.exe:: not found
\bin\sh: 3: memory-fileB.exe:: not found
\bin\sh: 4: timing-fileB.exe:: not found
\bin\sh: 3: memory-fileC.exe:: not found
\bin\sh: 4: timing-fileC.exe:: not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Is this even possible in the first place? I was just wondering if it were possible to be efficient using this method.

Any help is appreciated as I'd like to know more about the possibilities that makefiles allow. 
Thank you.

Comment: Look closely at the error, *\bin\sh: 3: memory-fileA.exe:: not found*. Note the extra colon (:), which is part of the file name. Do you have a file named `memory-fileA.exe:` that has a colon (:) at the end like that? I'm betting not. What's the purpose of the colon in `testing-$$i.exe: primary-$$i.o`? Did you mean, perhaps, `testing-$$i.exe primary-$$i.o`?

Comment: The idea with that line is to follow the static pattern rule, in order to have the file "memory-fileA.exe" created

Comment: Each line in a recipe is executed by the shell, not by Make itself. What you are attempting can probably be accomplished with simple `make` functions; look for `$(foreach ...)` and `$(patsubst ...)` as well as `$(eval ...)` in the GNU Make documentation.

Comment: @tripleee I understand what you are saying here, and I feel that that would be a great idea. If I'm right at what you're saying, its to use $(foreach program, $(SUFFIX), $(eval $(patsubstr ...))) but there is where I am lost. I've been looking around and I can't understand how to create a correct command to do the process. If possible, could you please steer me in the right direction? I'm sorry, i jsut can't wrap my head around what I can find elsewhere online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing shell and make constructs. As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) pointed the recipes of make rules are shell scripts, not other make rules.

Moreover, there are a few issues with your Makefile:

1. You explain that you want to use [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) but what you wrote is "*simple*" [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules).
2. You do not need to quote your suffixes. And you should not, make is not the shell, it preserves them. You will get errors because of this.
3. Your use of the standard `CXXFLAGS` make variable is extremely unusual. Traditionally it is limited to the compiler's flags, not the compiler itself for which `CXX` is used.
4. You are compiling source files and linking simultaneously. This too is not that usual. It causes useless re-compilations.
5. The `c++11` option of `g++` is new to me. Are you sure it is not `-std=c++11`?
6. The `vpath` directive is useless because you do not express dependencies on the header files. But let's keep it, I guess you do not show everything.

All-in-all, you can probably achieve want you want with:

```
vpath %.h ../headers/
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 -I../headers/
LDFLAGS  :=
SUFFIX   := fileA fileB fileC
TESTING  := $(patsubst %,testing-%.exe,$(SUFFIX))
MEMORY   := $(patsubst %,memory-%.exe,$(SUFFIX))

.PHONY: all

all: $(TESTING) $(MEMORY)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@

$(TESTING): testing-%.exe: primary-%.o memory.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(MEMORY): memory-%.exe: primary-%.o timing.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

The `%.o: %.cpp...` rule is a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules). It tells make how to produce any object file from the corresponding C++ source file. The two last rules are really [static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). The first of the two, for instance, declares that each target `testing-<suffix>.exe` listed in `$(TESTING)` depends on the corresponding `primary-<suffix>.o` and on `memory.o`. This single static pattern rule is thus equivalent to these 3 simple rules:

```
testing-fileA.exe: primary-fileA.o memory.o
    g++ primary-fileA.o memory.o -o testing-fileA.exe

testing-fileB.exe: primary-fileB.o memory.o
    g++ primary-fileB.o memory.o -o testing-fileB.exe

testing-fileC.exe: primary-fileC.o memory.o
    g++ primary-fileC.o memory.o -o testing-fileC.exe
```

No need for loops. Note that, if you correctly use the standard make variables `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`, you can drop the pattern rule (`%.o: %.cpp...`), it is one of the many [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) that make knows already.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it's very helpful and has shown me a better way of doing the process; however, I'm met with the command line telling me: no rule to make target 'testing-fileA.exe' needed by all. I've been having this problem for the majority of working with this problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Do you have `primary-fileA.cpp` and `memory.cpp` source files in the same directory as your Makefile? Do you invoke make from this same directory? Did you carefully copy-paste my example and replaced the leading spaces by tabs in the recipes?

Comment: I've posted into the original a problem that arises when using the code above - please examine it in the case there is something obvious I am missing. Thank you, I'm very grateful for your time and help.

Comment: As I wrote in the previous comment, looking at your edit, you do not have a `primary-fileA.cpp` file. How do you want to build `primary-fileA.o`? Without the source files there is nothing that make or `g++` can do.